# How to write in an Azure Website from a Webjob?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I know how to write into the storage, but how can I write in a web site from a web job? I want to use a webjob to insert some stuff in an azure database and images in a web site. I know that my webjob is:

uploaded in the `dir /App_Data/jobs/triggered/myjob`

but I can't write the a `dir /images`

Comment: Why not have your webapp expose an api to do just that?

Answer (score 3):

The your webjob has access to an environment variable called `%HOME%` using it like this `%HOME%\site\wwwroot` points you to the root of your site( `dir /` in your terminology). doing this

```
var imageDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%HOME%\site\wwwroot\images");
```

will give you the full path to your images folder in `imageDir`. Your webjob can write anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Azure WebJobs SDK does not support binding to databases or the file system. Only Azure Storage is supported out of the box.

However, you can manually create a connection to a database from a WebJob and perform DB operations.